# two NICs in the same subnet-- need to set up routing

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have a tricky case:

```
+---+                      +----+
|D1 +->eth0---------<-eth0-+D2  |
|   |                      |    |
|   +->eth1---------<-eth1-+    |
+---+                      +----+
```

On D2 `eth0` and `eth1` have IP addresses from the same subnet: `eth0` `10.1.1.1/24`, `eth1` `10.1.1.2/24`. Interfaces on D1 don't have addresses assigned and it acts like a switch.

Now, I want D2 to be able send the traffic to `10.1.1.2` via `eth0`, so the packet path has to be: D2(eth0)--D1(eth0)--D1(eth1)--D2(eth1).

At the moment when I ping `10.1.1.2` from D2 it sends packets locally, i.e. D1 doesn't get any. What should I change on D2 to achieve the desired behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: So you're wanting it to basically go between the two NIC's? Then you need to set up round robin bonding.

Comment: @Bratchley I am not familiar with bonding but it makes (in this case) two physical interfaces one logical interface, doesn't it? I think you should explain that in more detail.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood the question now that I re-read it.

Comment: @Bratchley, no I don't need bonding. Basically I want to "trick" the IP stack on D2, and have it send traffic with destination of eth1 interface (on D2) via eth0.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but this read similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275888/130303

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible with Linux. At least not within the routing layer. If a target address belongs to a local interface then the packet always goes through the loopback interface from where it cannot (by RfC) routed to the outside.

I thought it might be possible to use `iptables` and `DNAT` to change the target to an unused address in the subnet and use `ip neigh` to set the MAC address statically to the one of the other NIC but not even the `DNAT` rule is matched for packets to local addresses.

It may be possible with a virtual machine or with network namespaces so that the kernel does not see `10.1.1.1` on `eth0`. But you would need proxy ARP and DNAT for moving the incoming packets from the physical to the virtual interface.

If it's worth that effort?

Comment: thanks for response. It looks it is not worth the efforts spent :)  I'd better off find another machine, since all I need is to test throughput of D1 packet forwarding, so I can run netserver and netperf on physically different hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Network namespaces may be an option. They are essentially independent instances of the network stack so they should at least in theory be able to separate two interfaces.

Last time I tried playing with them though I couldn't get thing to work properly.