# Is it possible to initiate an IP connection between two NICs in same PC externally?

Tags: ip

If two NICs in a Linux machine are directly connected with each other using an external cable, then is it possible to initiate an IP connection between those two NICs over this cable?

I configured my two NICs `eth2` and `eth3` with IP addresses `10.10.123.2/24` and `10.10.123.3/24` respectively. Then I removed all the rules associated with those two interfaces from `local` table:

```
# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default 
# ip route show table local | grep -E "eth2|eth3"
#
```

..and added rules to `main` table that connections to `10.10.123.3` should go over `eth2` and connections to `10.10.123.2` should go over `eth3`:

```
# ip route get 10.10.123.3
10.10.123.3 dev eth2  src 10.10.123.2 
    cache 
# ip route get 10.10.123.2
10.10.123.2 dev eth3  src 10.10.123.3 
    cache 
#
```

Now if I send one ICMP "echo request" message to `10.10.123.2`(source IP will be `10.10.123.3`), then ARP request messages are put onto wire and I can see that `eth2` interface receives `Request who-has 10.10.123.2 tell 10.10.123.3`, but for some reason it does not reply to this. Any ideas why?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using a crossover ethernet cable?

Comment: @vik or are the interfaces 1Gbps in which case cross-over should not be needed?

Comment: lately all network adapters are coming with auto-sensing enabled. Unless the OP is using an ancient system or NICs, cross-over cable should not be a concern but it won't hurt either.

Comment: Both NICs support Auto-MDIX and are up(confirmed with `ip link` and `ethtool`).

Comment: I would believe the kernel won't respond to its own ARP broadcasts. You might come further by manual `arp` registration. Though I would suspect then the kernel will try to shortcut at the next level.

Comment: Just for my personal information, does this have any use or are you just trying for fun? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Try again without your route manipulation, but with

```
ip netns add not-me
ip link set eth2 netns not-me
```

This will remove eth2 from the default network namespace and you won't be able to see it.  To restore: `ip link set eth2 netns 1`.  To run commands in the new namespace: `ip netns exec not-me command...`.  Command could be `bash` to open a second (nested) shell.

Answer (score 2):

This is a script *ipcrossover* I wrote a while ago but it should still work. It sets up iptables so that you can send packets "to yourself", which is normally short-circuited by the kernel. It is based on [these answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface/128680).

```
#!/bin/bash
# posted in http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275888/119298 by meuh
# see https://serverfault.com/q/127636/294707
#  cmcginty Apr 2 '10 and Steve Kehlet answered Sep 8 '11

usage(){
        echo "$0: usage:
 config interface1 interface2
 show
 test
 tcpdump
 undo
This script sets up an iptables address translation to allow packets
to circulate over an external loopback cable between two interfaces.
You need to be root. Example usage:
 $0 config eth0:1 eth1
 $0 test
" >&2
        exit 1
}

getmac(){
        $setdebug
        local interface=${1?'interface'}
        ip link show $interface |
        awk '/link\/ether/ { print $2 }'
}
getaddr(){
        $setdebug
        local interface=${1?'interface'}
        ip addr show $interface |
        awk '/ inet / { split($2,x,"/"); print x[1] }'
}
# return true if have name of 2 interfaces
haveconfig(){
        $setdebug
        [ -n "$if1" -a -n "$if2" ] &&
        ip link show "$if1" &&
        ip link show "$if2"
}
# set variables from $if1 and $if2
setup(){
        $setdebug
        if ! haveconfig >/dev/null
        then    haveconfig >&2
                echo "Start with 'config' and 2 valid interfaces" >&2
                usage
        fi
        realprefix=10.50
        fakeprefix=10.60
        real1=$realprefix.0.1
        fake1=$fakeprefix.0.1
        real2=$realprefix.1.1
        fake2=$fakeprefix.1.1
        mac1=$(getmac $if1)
        mac2=$(getmac $if2)
}
doconfig(){
        doifconfig
        doiptables
        doroute
        doarp
        echo "eg: ping $fake2"
}
# Give IPs to the interfaces, and put them on separate networks:
doifconfig(){
        $setdebug
        ifconfig $if1 $real1/24
        ifconfig $if2 $real2/24
}

# set up a double NAT scenario: two new fake networks used to reach the
# other. On the way out, source NAT to your fake network. On the way in,
# fix the destination. And vice versa for the other network:
doiptables(){
        $setdebug
        # nat source IP $real1 -> $fake1 when going to $fake2
        iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $real1 -d $fake2 -j SNAT --to-source $fake1
        # nat source IP $real2 -> $fake2 when going to $fake1
        iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $real2 -d $fake1 -j SNAT --to-source $fake2

        # nat inbound $fake1 -> $real1
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $fake1 -j DNAT --to-destination $real1
        # nat inbound $fake2 -> $real2
        iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $fake2 -j DNAT --to-destination $real2
}

# tell the system how to get to each fake network
doroute(){
        $setdebug
        ip route flush cache
        ip route add $fake2 dev $if1 src $real1
        ip route add $fake1 dev $if2 src $real2
}
# prepopulate the arp entries
doarp(){
        $setdebug
        ip neigh add $fake2 lladdr $mac2 dev $if1
        ip neigh add $fake1 lladdr $mac1 dev $if2
}
doshow(){
        $setdebug
        iptables -L -t nat -v -n -x
        ip route get $fake1
        ip route get $fake2
        arp -n
}
# undo all configuration
doundo(){
        iptables -F -t nat
        ip route del $fake2 dev $if1
        ip route del $fake1 dev $if2 
        ip route flush cache
        #arp -i $realif1 -d $fake2
        #arp -i $realif2 -d $fake1
        ip neigh del $fake2 lladdr $mac2 dev $if1
        ip neigh del $fake1 lladdr $mac1 dev $if2
        ip addr del $real1/24 dev $if1
        ip addr del $real2/24 dev $if2
}
# tcpdump of just the wanted packets, in case using nfs on interface
dotcpdump(){
        tcpdump -n -e -i fm1-gb1 ether src $mac1 or ether src $mac2 or ether dst $mac1 or ether dst $mac2
}
showpacketcounts(){
        echo -n "$1 "
        local realif=${1%:*}
        ifconfig "$realif" |
        awk '/packets/{printf "%s %-20s",$1,$2; if(/TX/)printf "\n"}'
}
showiptablescounts(){
        iptables -L -t nat -v -x |
        awk '       $3~/[SD]NAT/ { result = result " " $1 " " $3}
                END {print "iptables counts " result }'
}
showcounts(){
        showpacketcounts $if1
        showpacketcounts $if2
        showiptablescounts
}
showdiffs(){
        echo -e "==\n$old\n==\n$new" |
        awk '/^==/{ part++; i = 0; next }
                { inp[part][++i] = $0 }
        END { end = i; for(i = 1;i<=end;i++)print inp[1][i] "\n" inp[2][i] }'
}
# use netstat -l -t to see what services you could test
dotest(){
        old=$(showcounts)
        for ip in $fake1 $fake2
        do      ping -c 4 $ip # -W 1
                echo
                traceroute -M udp $ip # -m 2
                echo
                rpcinfo -p $ip | head -3
                echo
        done
        new=$(showcounts)
        showdiffs
}

# eg ping $fake2 goes out $if1, the source IP $real1 gets NATted to $fake1,
# and as it comes into $if2 the destination $fake2 gets NATted to $real2.
# And the reply takes a similar journey.

# to use iperf to test throughput. Bind to the correct IPs, and be certain
# which IP you're contacting (the other end's fake address):
# server
#./iperf -B $real2 -s
# client: your destination is the other end's fake address
#./iperf -B $real1 -c $fake2 -t 60 -i 10

setdebug= 
case $- in
*x*)        setdebug='set -x' ;; 
esac
PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin

# read saved config
CONFIGFILE=~/.ipcrossover
if [ -s $CONFIGFILE ]
then        source $CONFIGFILE
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do      cmd=$1; shift
        case $cmd in
        config) if [ $# -ge 2 ] && ip link show "$1" >/dev/null
                then    if1=$1
                        if2=$2
                        shift 2
                        echo "if1=$if1; if2=$if2" >$CONFIGFILE
                fi
                setup
                doconfig ;;
        show|test|undo|tcpdump)
                setup
                do$cmd ;;
        *)      usage ;;
        esac
done
```

The usage is fairly simple

```
sudo ipcrossover config eth0 eth1
ping 10.60.0.1
ping 10.60.1.1
sudo ipcrossover test
```

(or use aliases `eth0:1 eth1:1` if you don't want to disturb your existing network on these interfaces).  Tear down the config with `sudo ipcrossover undo`.
It works by adding new ip addresses 10.50.0.1 and 10.60.0.1 on the first interface and 10.50.1.1 and 10.60.1.1 on the second, and as set in the script:

```
        realprefix=10.50
        fakeprefix=10.60
        real1=$realprefix.0.1
        fake1=$fakeprefix.0.1
        real2=$realprefix.1.1
        fake2=$fakeprefix.1.1
```

Eg `ping $fake2` goes out interface $if1, the source IP $real1 gets NATted to $fake1,
and as it comes into $if2 the destination $fake2 gets NATted to $real2.
And the reply takes a similar journey.

To use `iperf` to test throughput, bind to the correct IPs, and be certain
which IP you're contacting (the other end's fake address):
On the server `./iperf -B $real2 -s`.
On the client your destination is the other end's fake address:
`./iperf -B $real1 -c $fake2 -t 60 -i 10`.

Verify that it is working by unplugging the cable and checking the ping stops! 
Make sure you read the [linked answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface/128680) to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Linux kernel answers to any ARP request for any interface it has from any interface. This behavior is sometimes undesirable.

To change this behavior you need to modify some kernel parameters with:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_ignore 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/arp_ignore
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_announce
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/arp_announce
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/arp_filter
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/arp_filter
```

You can also change this for all interfaces in your machine with:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_ignore 
echo 2 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_announce
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_filter
```

Take a look at what these networking kernel paramters mean and adjust them to your specific needs if these last commands do not work as you expect:

> ### `arp_ignore` - INTEGER
>
> Define different modes for sending replies in response to
>           received ARP requests that resolve local target IP addresses:
>
> - 0 - (default): reply for any local target IP address, configured on any interface
> - 1 - reply only if the target IP address is local address configured on the incoming interface
> - 2 - reply only if the target IP address is local address configured on the incoming interface and both with the
>         sender's IP address are part from same subnet on this interface
> - 3 - do not reply for local addresses configured with scope host,
>         only resolutions for global and link addresses are replied
> - 4-7 - reserved
> - 8 - do not reply for all local addresses
>
> The max value from conf/{all,interface}/arp_ignore is used
>           when ARP request is received on the {interface}
>
> ### `arp_announce` - INTEGER
>
> Define different restriction levels for announcing the local source IP address from IP packets in ARP requests sent on interface:
>
> - 0 - (default) Use any local address, configured on any interface
> - 1 - Try to avoid local addresses that are not in the target's
>         subnet for this interface. This mode is useful when target
>         hosts reachable via this interface require the source IP
>         address in ARP requests to be part of their logical network
>         configured on the receiving interface. When we generate the
>         request we will check all our subnets that include the
>         target IP and will preserve the source address if it is from
>         such subnet. If there is no such subnet we select source
>         address according to the rules for level 2.
> - 2 - Always use the best local address for this target.
>         In this mode we ignore the source address in the IP packet
>         and try to select local address that we prefer for talks with
>         the target host. Such local address is selected by looking
>         for primary IP addresses on all our subnets on the outgoing
>         interface that include the target IP address. If no suitable
>         local address is found we select the first local address
>         we have on the outgoing interface or on all other interfaces,
>         with the hope we will receive reply for our request and
>         even sometimes no matter the source IP address we announce.
>
> The max value from conf/{all,interface}/arp_announce is used.
>
> Increasing the restriction level gives more chance for
>           receiving answer from the resolved target while decreasing
>           the level announces more valid sender's information.
>
> ### `arp_filter` - BOOLEAN
>
> - 1 - Allows you to have multiple network interfaces on the same
>         subnet, and have the ARPs for each interface be answered
>         based on whether or not the kernel would route a packet from
>         the ARP'd IP out that interface (therefore you must use source
>         based routing for this to work). In other words it allows control
>         of which cards (usually 1) will respond to an arp request.
> - 0 - (default) The kernel can respond to arp requests with addresses
>         from other interfaces. This may seem wrong but it usually makes
>         sense, because it increases the chance of successful communication.
>         IP addresses are owned by the complete host on Linux, not by
>         particular interfaces. Only for more complex setups like load-
>         balancing, does this behaviour cause problems.
>
> arp_filter for the interface will be enabled if at least one of
>           conf/{all,interface}/arp_filter is set to TRUE,
>           it will be disabled otherwise

You can see more relevant network parameters in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

Comment: ping doesn't work in that case when I loopback the same NIC with multiple ethernet ports on one machine?

Answer (score 1):

I used Linux network namespaces to accomplish this. I created a separate namespace, call it `ns1`, for one of the ports.

I added the interface `eth1` to that namespace and assigned it the IP address `192.168.2.1/24`. Also within the `ns1` namespace, I forced all network traffic in and out of this namespace to use `eth1`:

`ip route add default dev eth1`

Then I assigned the IP address `192.168.1.1/24` to another Ethernet port, `eth0`, still residing in the root namespace.  I also added a route in the root namespace to the `ns1` namespace:

`ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0`

Now you can ping 192.168.1.1 from 192.168.2.1 and vice versa. Unplug the cable between eth0 and eth1 and watch packets stop flowing.

You can also verify that you're using the cable by checking the bandwidth via iperf. In the `ns1` namespace, run an iperf server:

`iperf -s -f m -i 5`

Run an iperf client in the root namespace:

`iperf -c 192.168.2.1 -t 60`